# Cite-marks in List of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, citing

My list of figures currently contains the cite-marks next the caption:

[image]

**How do I get rid of them in the list of figures?**

This is how the first figure is defined.
If I put the `\cite{}` outside of the `\caption{}` it is displayed in the next line:

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \input{Figures/gestural-interfaces-flowdiagram}
  \caption{The basic components of gestural systems\cite[p. 13]{Saffer}}
  \label{cv:gestural-interfaces-flowdiagram}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional argument for `\caption`:

```
\caption[Without cite for the LoF/LoT]{With the cite \cite{test} in the document}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\centering
A  
\caption[The basic components of gestural systems]{The basic components of gestural systems\cite[p. 13]{Saffer}}
\label{cv:gestural-interfaces-flowdiagram}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Saffer} A test item
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]